# Quale delle due risposte alla domanda "A cosa vado incontro?" è corretta?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Se mi chiedessero

> A che cosa vado incontro?

Quale sarebbe, tra le seguenti, l'alternativa corretta?

> A) Non ho idea **di cosa** tu vada incontro
>
> B) Non ho idea **di a che cosa** tu vada incontro

La prima sembra sbagliata perché il verbo "andare incontro" sembra presupporre un complemento di termine (andare in contro **a** qualcosa), ma la seconda suona molto male.

Qual è la risposta giusta?

Comment: La seconda è corretta, ma una versione che suona meglio è *Non ho idea di a cosa tu vada incontro* o *Non ho idea di a cosa tu stia andando incontro* (a seconda del contesto)

Comment: E ovviamente anche: Non ho idea di ciò a cui vai incontro.

Comment: Personalmente, risponderei: “Non ne ho idea”.

Comment: A me _Non ho idea **di** a cosa tu vada incontro_ suona malissimo, a me verrebbe assolutamente da dirlo senza il _di_. Sarebbe scorretto?

Comment: A me sembra che nessuna di queste frasi sia pronunciabile in italiano. Rispondereste davvero, spontaneamente, in qualcuno di questi modi?

Comment: @DaG Effettivamente, no, se dovessi scegliere io quale forma usare non sceglierei nemmeno quella senza il _di_, credo che sceglierei qualcos'altro in base al contesto. Però quella forma con il _di a_ sinceramente mi fa sanguinare le orecchie :)

Comment: @DaG più che la risposta a quella precisa domanda, mi interessava l'uso corretto delle preposizioni in casi simili. Ad esempio volevo capire se espressioni come "Devo riflettere *su se* farlo o no" o "Dipende *da a chi* lo dici" fossero giuste o meno dato che, come hai sottolineato, non "suonano" benissimo.

Comment: @Nicol, quel "di" non riesco a vederlo, le considerazioni che fai sono corrette in parte, ed io risponderei semplicemente "non ho idea a cosa vai incontro" o "non ho idea a cosa tu vada incontro" o "non ho idea dove andrai" o "non ho idea incontro a cosa andrai"...

Answer (score 2):

I think the expression "non avere idea" holds the preposition "di":

- non ho idea di cosa mangerò stasera
- non hai idea di cosa ti aspetti
- non ho idea di chi siano quei due li
- non avete idea di dove siano le mie scarpe?

However, "non ho idea di a cosa tu vada incontro" doesn't sound right. To work around this problem you could answer with a generic yet effective "non ne ho la minima idea". Answering "non lo so" and "non so a cosa tu vada incontro" would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente credo che con "non ho idea..." non si riesca a fare una frase che suona bene, piuttosto è preferibile usare "non so a cosa andrai incontro" (o anche "potresti andare"), così come un semplice "non ne ho idea" è decisamente più chiaro.

Comment: scusa, non suona bene "non ho idea a cosa andrai incontro"...? Tuttavia, "non ho idea di cosa vuoi dire con la risposta" (-1)

Comment: No, non suona bene "non ho idea a cosa andrai incontro", @mle. E se tu non hai idea del significato di una risposta, perché le dai -1, anziché cercare di capirla o chiedere un chiarimento?

Comment: senza fonte e con "personalmente credo", "preferibile usare", "decisamente più chiaro" (sbucato dal nulla e senza senso, poteva spiegarlo almeno) mi suona di climax usato per rendere risposta un qualcosa che risposta non è a leggere. I voti sono bloccati dopo 5 minuti, se modifica la risposta si sbloccano..

Comment: In merito alla frase "non ho idea a cosa andrai incontro", ti suona male per l´uso del verbo o per la mancanza del "di"? Se è per la seconda continuo a non capire perché qui in Sicilia è usato, inoltre da me piú volte anche scritto (raramente corretto) in saggi, tesi all`Uni e scuola  (per citare una fonte ad esempio: https://books.google.de/books?id=39u9DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT7&lpg=PT7&dq=a+cosa+ti+riferisci,+non+ho+idea&source=bl&ots=z4TnjfttTZ&sig=loKl87JbHSaWLuheBI2X704B2Jk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLjqfpnN7TAhWLhSwKHbNKDioQ6AEIYzAJ#v=onepage&q=a%20cosa%20ti%20riferisci%2C%20non%20ho%20idea&f=false )

Answer (score 0):

Io direi:

non ho idea **a** cosa tu vada incontro.

Perché nella domanda è stata usata la preposizione "a" quindi credo che vada usata nello stesso modo anche nella risposta

Answer (score 0):

Mi sembra che la domanda riguardi la *correttezza grammaticale* della frase: in questo caso, mi sembra ci siano pochi dubbi. Si ha un'idea **di** qualcosa (complemento di argomento, "di" = "a riguardo di", "a proposito di"), e quindi, innegabilmente, la frase corretta è

> Non ho idea di quello a cui vai incontro.

Contraendo un po', si può togliere "quello" e sostituirlo con la subordinata che lo definisce:

> Non ho idea di a che cosa vai incontro.

Le due preposizioni vicine ("di" e "a") non si danno affatto fastidio: "di" sta nella principale ("non ho idea della cosa"), e "a" nella subordinata ("alla quale vai incontro"). La frase sopra è senza dubbio corretta.

Si può obiettare che nell'uso comune non si sente quasi mai questa costruzione. Neanche si sente "sono uscito con la ragazza con cui vado all'università", ma si semplifica (svilendola) in "sono uscito con una ragazza, sai quella che viene all'università con me?"; non per questo dobbiamo pensare che le subordinate siano "sbagliate" o "suonino male". Se proprio preferisci fare una parafrasi, come altri ti hanno già suggerito, usa tranquillamente "non ne ho idea" o "non so a cosa vai incontro".

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Ho un paio di dubbi sulla tua risposta: 1) Che c'entra la metrica latina? Qualcuno l'aveva menzionata? Non lo trovo... 2) «Le due proposizioni vicine ("di" e "a") non si danno affatto fastidio»: sì e no. È una formulazione che eviterei. Ti viene in mente qualche esempio tratto da buoni scrittori con una frase del genere? (Non è una domanda retorica.)

Comment: 3) Quanto al discorso dello “svilire” etc., è un dato di fatto – né buono né cattivo – che l'italiano, come ogni lingua naturale, ha vari registri. Non si parla tra amici come se si scrivesse un atto giudiziario, non si scrive un articolo di giornale nello stesso stile in cui si parla con la fidanzata a letto, e così via. E questa è una ricchezza della lingua, non uno svilimento.

Comment: @DaG Grazie del benvenuto! Scusa: quello sulla metrica latina è un commento sarcastico. Mi sembrava che la discussione fosse passata da "è corretto?" a "è bello e piacevole?", e volevo togliere l'attenzione da quanto la frase corretta "suonasse bene". È una battuta, ed effettivamente farò meglio a toglierla :)

Comment: 3) "Svilire" è l'azione del "togliere valore", "ridurre il pregio". È vero che esistono diversi registri, e concorderai con me che il registro colloquiale mira principalmente ad abbassare il linguaggio, evitando costruzioni forbite che vengono percepite come eccessive in un contesto verbale. Mentre sono un fermo oppositore di questo modo di pensare ("colloquiale" e "chiaro" non devono necessariamente coincidere con "elementare" e "banale"), riconosco che nella vita di tutti i giorni certe costruzioni non si usano - non per questo sono scorrette.

Comment: (Tra l'altro ho commesso un errore di ortografia piuttosto serio: ho confuso "proposizione" - frase - con "preposizione". "Di" e "a" sono *pre*posizioni.)

Comment: 2) Su due piedi non mi viene in mente un esempio nella letteratura. Mi vengono in mente un sacco di "badare a che succeda...", ma non è la stessa cosa. C'è da dire che, ad ogni modo, si tratta di un caso abbastanza raro da essere solitamente trattato con una perifrasi, come molti comunque hanno già suggerito. Certo, la frase, come è stata proposta, è corretta, e la trovo perfettamente coerente con un registro alto. Cercherò esempi.

Comment: Ho provveduto alle *pre*posizioni; giusto, non l'avevo notato. Quanto al registro colloquiale etc., scusami ma non ha molto senso essere “fermi oppositori” di un modo di parlare a favore di un altro. Ogni parlante della lingua italiana parla e scrive come può e vuole, e a seconda delle circostanze della vita. Ai linguisti e ai curiosi delle questioni linguistiche può interessare studiare queste differenze, ma non è molto scientifico esprimere un giudizio. Sarebbe come criticare il colore di una foglia o le abitudini alimentari di un animale.

Comment: @DaG Concordo sulla scientificità; resto della mia idea sul fatto che abbassare la lingua sia sempre e comunque male (chi parla male pensa male), ma non è questo il nodo del discorso e non ne parlerò oltre. Quello che intendo dire nella risposta, però (forse mi sono espresso male), è che "non suona bene" non è un motivo per rifiutare il periodo, come hanno fatto alcune altre risposte, proprio come la scarsa frequenza nel linguaggio "comune" di una composizione complessa (con frasi subordinate, termini più selezionati, etc.) non deve significare che quella costruzione vada scartata.

Comment: Grazie della risposta argomentata. Sul “suonare bene” sono disposto a una maggior apertura: è la “funzione poetica” del linguaggio naturale, che non è solo un codice come può esserlo il calcolo proposizionale in logica, ma ha anche potenzialità estetiche, e non solo in ambito letterario (e persino vari fenomeni linguistici diacronici, come l'assimilazione, la dissimilazione, l'epentesi derivano in ultima analisi dal “suonare bene”), ma let's agree to disagree.